# Same-domain hosting for local Angular CLI and remote iframe

Tags: angular, iframe, cross-domain, angular-cli, angular5

I have a legacy hosting environment on the network that uses `iframe` to load apps, configurable to have `iframe` point at any URL, so one can test a locally running web app.

And I have an app with Angular 5.x + CLI 1.6.x that needs to be tested that way, from a Windows 7 machine.

So far the only way I could make the two pieces work together was with `--host` pointing at my local machine:

```
$ ng serve --host=MYMACHINE.local.net.com
```

I also had to use `--public-host` to point at the hosting environment, or else it didn't accept the response headers.

The problem is however, the app uses an internal service to access and resize the containing `iframe` correctly, which works fine when eventually hosted on the network, but when running locally I'm having the cross-domain problem - the local app cannot change the containing `iframe` because the two are on two separate domains.

Is there any way to solve this?

And I can't just have `--host` point at the hosting server, because even though the app can run locally, after changing local `drivers\host` file to resolve that address into the local machine, it creates a problem with the URL for the test environment, which cannot be opened after such address override.

Comment: Have you tried using [proxies](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/blob/master/docs/documentation/stories/proxy.md) for this issue ? That's usually how I correct my CORS issue

Comment: @trichetriche I've been using proxies for internal use of HTTP services. But for this issue - I'm not sure how that can help me.

Comment: Using a proxy avoid cors issues. I gave you that link for introducing proxies as an answer to your issue, but it really is a server issue : for instance, use apache proxies if you have an apache server. That's how I got rid of my problems.